# Rails, nested attributes, created in new action,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, simple-form, nested-attributes

I have a order system where a user selects products that's being saved in a cookie. It is then retrieved by the system when continued to the order page.

```
@order = Order.new
unless @cart.nil?
  @cart.each do | product |
    @order.quantities.build :product => product, :quantity => 1
  end
end
```

However I want the user to be able to update the quantity which is a field in the quantity model that belongs to product and order.

How can I access this newly made "@order.quantities" in my form view?

```
    <%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :quantities do |q| %>
       <%= q.input :quantity %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, :class => "main_button right" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :quantities
    has_many :products, through: :quantities
end

class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :product
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `f.object` this returns an object that is used to build form (in your case it equals `@order`.

If you would like to use nested form (using `accept_nested_attributes`) you need [`simple-fields-for`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models). Do not forget add **`accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities`** to `Order.rb`. Something like this should work

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :quantities do |q| %>
    <%= q.input :quantity %>
    ...
```

if you would like just to print a value of the quantity

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :quantities do |q| %>
    <%= "You have #{q.object.quantity} quantity" %>
    ...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? =) I mean, just putting f.object.quantities  gives me:

#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Quantity:0x007febcb65d5b0>

Comment: I see. it is because `@order.quantities` returns a AR relation. It is difficult to say what you need exactly and how you would like to build a form. For example if you would like to build nested form (using accept_nested_attributes) you need write [simple_fields_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#simple-fields-for) as `f.simple_fields_for :quantities do |quantity| ...`.

Comment: thanks, I want to edit the new quantities that I have built from the cookie.

Comment: That leaves me with a blank (only one) quantity input field

Comment: And it isn't filled with the prewritten quantity (1).

Comment: `simple_fields_for` not `fields_for`

Comment: No difference, same output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37451/discussion-between-philip-and-gotva)